# How to get checked state of <p:selectBooleanCheckbox> in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, selectbooleancheckbox

Hi i want a textbox enable or disable dependig of a checkbox status

i have this code  but nothing happens i´ve tried using  others find methods.

```
document.getElementById('j_idt6:docName')
```

and

```
('j_idt6:docName')
```

But doesn´t works.

This is my whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<title></title>

</h:head>
<h:body>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#j_idt6\\:singleDoc').change( function() {
var isChecked = this.checked;

if(isChecked) {
    $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find('#j_idt6\\:docName').prop("disabled",true); 
} else {  
    $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find('#j_idt6\\:docName').prop("disabled",false);
}

});
});//]]>  

</script>


<h:form>

    <p:panel id="panel" header="Test">

        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">

            <p:outputLabel for="singleDoc" id="msgSingleDoc"
                value="Is a single document." />
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="singleDoc" />

            <p:outputLabel for="docName" value="Name of the document" />
            <p:inputText id="docName" required="false" />


        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

I found a different way to find the elements here http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-get-jsf-id-via-jquery/

I´m using Primefaces 5

but still nothing happens

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<title>ORC Sysmar</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formulario:singleDoc')).change( function() {
var isChecked = this.checked;

if(isChecked) {
            $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formulario:docName')).prop("disabled",true); 
 } else {  
            $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formulario:docName')).prop("disabled",false);
 }

 });
});//]]>  

</script>




<h:form id="formulario">

<p:panel id="panel" header="Test">

    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
        <p:outputLabel for="singleDoc" id="msgSingleDoc"
            value="Is a single document." />
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="singleDoc" />

        <p:outputLabel for="docName" value="Name of the document" />
        <p:inputText id="docName" required="false" />


    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your time and answers

Comment: Would you mind doing it with ajax or do you explicitly intend client-side functionallity?

Comment: I´m thinkig in  client side

Comment: It would help if you tell the exact PrimeFaces version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closer at the generated HTML output.

This,

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="singleDoc" />
```

generates the following HTML (in order to be able to apply jQuery UI look'n'feel on checkboxes):

```
<div id="formulario:singleDoc" class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input id="formulario:singleDoc_input" name="formulario:singleDoc_input" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-c"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You're attempting to hook a `change` event on `<div class="ui-chkbox">`. This indeed just won't work. It isn't a `<input type="checkbox">` as expected by this kind of script which you apparently randomly found on the Internet in some example targeted specifically on `<input type="checkbox">` (and a pretty browser-centric example too; hooking `change` event on checkboxes is namely not MSIE friendly).

You need to listen on `click` event of the HTML element having among others `ui-state-default` class (that's thus the one also having `ui-chkbox-box` class). Then, you should investigate the checked state of the *actual* `<input type="checkbox">` inside the same `ui-chkbox` container which is being hidden behind the fancy look'n'feel.

So, all in all, this should do:

```
<h:outputScript target="body">
    $(document).on("click", "#formulario\\:singleDoc .ui-chkbox-box", function() {
        var isChecked = $(this).closest(".ui-chkbox").find(":checkbox").get(0).checked;
        $("#formulario\\:docName").attr("disabled", isChecked); 
    });
</h:outputScript>
```

Note that I made 4 improvements as well:

1. Use `<h:outputScript target="body">` instead of a clumsy `<script>$(window).load()`.
2. Use `$(document).on(event, selector, function)` instead of `$(selector).on(event, function)`, otherwise this all breaks once you ajax-update the elements behind `selector`.
3. Use `isChecked` directly instead of comparing it in an `if-else` block which sets exactly the same value as `isChecked` itself.
4. No need to grab an element which already has an unique ID by DOM traversing. Just grab it directly. There can be only 1 in entire HTML DOM tree.

To make it all yet better, put the script this in a real `.js` file which you include via `<h:outputScript name>`. JS code belongs in `.js` files, not in `.xhtml` files. To make it *yet* better, use smart CSS class names instead of IDs. E.g.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox ... styleClass="fieldtoggler" />

<p:inputText ... styleClass="togglablefield" />
<p:inputText ... styleClass="togglablefield" />
<p:inputText ... styleClass="togglablefield" />
```

With

```
$(document).on("click", "form .fieldtoggler .ui-chkbox-box", function() {
    var checked = $(this).closest(".ui-chkbox").find(":checkbox").get(0).checked;
    $(this).closest("form").find(".togglablefield").attr("disabled", checked);
});
```

This way it's so much better reusable by just specifying the appropriate CSS classes.

Comment: BaluscC thanks for your answer, In your javascript i´ve changed "#form\\:singleDoc this for "#formulario\\:singleDoc, because this is the id what I have for the form, but does´t works.  It how looks now http://pastie.org/9501886

Comment: Why did you change `click` event as shown in my answer by non-existent `hover` event?

Comment: Im sorry because with click doesn´t runs I tried with other events but with the click events looks like this http://pastie.org/9501915

Comment: Works for me. I'm using PrimeFaces 5.0. I don't have loaded another jQuery file via a manually fiddled `<script>` tag. PrimeFaces as being a jQuery based JSF component library already auto-includes jQuery all by itself. Try removing that `<script>` tag on `jquery-git.js`. Don't forget to check JS console for errors as well.

Comment: Man yes its works I just restarted tomcat and works, thaks to teach me so much